# having a map of strings how to compare it to given string

Tags: c++, search, boost, dictionary, text-search

We have map of string pairs like name:location (unix like absolute location a la `myfolder/`). We are given with some location a la `myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile`. How to find which of maps location fit to given url most?

Example we have a map like:

```
service1:myfolder/
service2:myfolder/mysubfolder/
service3:myfolder/myothersubfolder/
service4:myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile
```

We are given value `myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile/blablabla/` (string). 
We want to find out to which item in our map it relates the most.
Search result shall be `service4` as map item with most related content.

So how to find by given string value to which map element it relates the most?

Please provide some code because I am C++ nube and do not get how to inplement such thing?

So I simplified a problem a bit - [now all relation I need is in how deep given path is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997723/having-a-map-with-paths-how-to-compare-tham-to-given-path) which in string case can be aceived by just iteratin over all maps paths looking at thare langth , searching for appearence in given path and remembering most long map item path found in given path.

Comment: You tagged your question boost - is a bidirectional map an option?

Comment: What have you currently tried? Do you have any code that you can share?

Comment: If a bidirectional map ([Bimap in boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)) is "correct", then what is your actual question? (Of course, I see that you've edited this, and you're not looking for a strict mapping - you have some notion of "most similar". It sounds like you need to really define what you mean by that, then search your map for the key-value pair with the maximum "similarity" of value to target.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. If you need to run many queries:

   1. Build the inverse map or use bidirectional map.
   2. Find first larger element using upper_bound and

      - If you need element with longest common prefix, check this and previous (last smaller) element and choose the one with longer common prefix.
      - If you need element that is a prefix, scan back until you find an element that is a prefix.
2. If you need just one query, simple linear search will be quicker (building the inverse map takes *O(n log(n))*, while one iteration takes just *O(n)*), plus it's easier to implement. Simply iterate over the map, for each value calculate the prefix length and remember the best match so far (I wanted to suggest using `std::max_element`, but it implements maximum by comparison operator while you need maximum by metrics).

Answer (score 1):

If your map is defined like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string,std::string> MyMap;
MyMap my_map;
```

...and the search term is defined like this:

```
std::string my_key_to_find = "service4";
```

...then you can get the value associated with this key like this:

```
std::string found_val;
MyMap::const_iterator it = my_map.find(my_key_to_find);
if( it != my_map.end() )
  found_val = it->second;
else
  std::cout << "Key not found!\n";
```

Comment: I think Blender wants to search for a partial key

Comment: I think he wants to search for the value to get the key.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to search for keys by value (string), where the matching values are substrings of the provided search term.  I don't think there is an easy solution for this as a general problem (i.e. arbitrary strings and all their substrings).

However, the strings used as values in your example have a specific structure (i.e. file system paths).  You can exploit this structure to come up with a clean solution.  First, make a [bi-directional map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example4).  Then, implement the following lookup process:

1. If path is empty, fail.
2. Reverse lookup in the map based on the request path
3. If found, return associated value.
4. Pop the last component off the path.
5. Loop.

If the list is short, you might just want to loop over the list of (key,value) pairs and select the key where the value is the most similar (i.e. longest substring in common).