# Having a map with paths how to compare tham to given path?

Tags: c++, search, boost, path, boost-filesystem

We have map of boost path to string pairs like name:location (absolute location paths a la `usr/myfolder/`). We are given with some location a la `usr/myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile`. How to find which of maps location fit to given url most?

Example we have a map like which we can resort if we need:

```
service1:myfolder/
service2:myfolder/mysubfolder/
service3:myfolder/myothersubfolder/
service4:myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile
```

We are given value `myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile/blablabla/` (path).
We want to find out to which item in our map it relates the most.
Search result shall be `service4` as map item with most related content.

So how to find by given string value to which map element it relates the most?

So [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979442/having-a-map-of-strings-how-to-compare-it-to-given-string) was about general string case but I had some reconfiguration so no I just work on boost paths.

Comment: When you say it's in a map, do you mean something like a `std::map` or a vector?  And are they sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

**EDIT**

Since I finally needed something similar myself, and this question remains open.  Here is some code I played around with.  Both straight up string distance and also applying the Levenshtein algorithm to the path tokens.

**C++ Code**

```
/*
----- String based Levenshtein ----
Matching : this/is/a/strange/path

0 : this/is/a/strange/path
2 : this/is/a/strong/path
2 : that/is/a/strange/path
4 : is/this/a/strange/path
5 : this/is/a/strange
13 : this/is/a
15 : this/is
16 : that/was
18 : this
24 : completely/different/folder

----- Path based Levenshtein ----
Matching : this/is/a/strange/path

0 : this/is/a/strange/path
1 : this/is/a/strange
2 : this/is/a/strong/path
2 : that/is/a/strange/path
2 : this/is/a
2 : is/this/a/strange/path
3 : this/is
4 : this
7 : that/was
8 : completely/different/folder
*/

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

/// returns the smaller of two parameters
template< typename T >
    T levmin( T v1, T v2 )
    {   return ( v1 < v2 ) ? v1 : v2; }

/// Returns the Levenshtein distance between the specified strings
template < typename T, typename T_STR > 
    typename T_STR::size_type levstr(const T_STR &s1, const T_STR &s2)
{
    typename T_STR::size_type l1 = s1.length(), l2 = s2.length();
    std::vector< typename T_STR::size_type > d( ( l1 + 1 ) * ( l2 + 1 ) );

    typename T_STR::size_type i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i <= l1; i++ )
        d[ i * l2 ] = i;

    for ( i = 0; i <= l2; i++ )
        d[ i ] = i;

    for ( i = 1; i <= l1; i++ )
        for ( j = 1; j <= l2; j++ )
            d[ i * l2 + j ] = levmin( levmin( d[ ( i - 1 ) * l2 + j ] + 1, d[ i * l2 + ( j - 1 ) ] + 1 ),
                                      d[ ( i - 1 ) * l2 + ( j - 1 ) ] + ( s1[ i - 1 ] == s2[ j - 1 ] ? 0 : 1 ) 
                                    );

    return d[ ( l1 * l2 ) + l2 ];       
}

/// Returns the Levenshtein distance between the specified split paths
template < typename T, typename T_STR, typename T_LST > 
    typename T_STR::size_type levpath(const T_LST &lst1, const T_LST &lst2)
{
    typename T_STR::size_type l1 = lst1.size(), l2 = lst2.size();
    std::vector< typename T_STR::size_type > d( ( l1 + 1 ) * ( l2 + 1 ) );

    typename T_STR::size_type i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i <= l1; i++ )
        d[ i * l2 ] = i;

    for ( i = 0; i <= l2; i++ )
        d[ i ] = i;

    for ( i = 1; i <= l1; i++ )
        for ( j = 1; j <= l2; j++ )
            d[ i * l2 + j ] = levmin( levmin( d[ ( i - 1 ) * l2 + j ] + 1, d[ i * l2 + ( j - 1 ) ] + 1 ),
                                      d[ ( i - 1 ) * l2 + ( j - 1 ) ] + levstr< T, T_STR>( lst1[ i - 1 ], lst2[ j - 1 ] )
                                    );

    return d[ ( l1 * l2 ) + l2 ];       
}

/// Generic split path function
/*
    Returns a vector of path tokens
*/
template < typename T, typename T_STR, typename T_LST >
    T_LST splitpath( const T_STR &s, const T sep )
    {   T_LST lst;
        typename T_STR::size_type i = 0, l = 0;
        while( T_STR::npos != ( i = s.find_first_of( sep, i ) ) )
        {   if ( l < i )
                lst.push_back( T_STR( s, l, i - l ) );
            l = ++i;
        } // end while
        if ( l < s.length() )
            lst.push_back( T_STR( s, l, s.length() - l ) );
        return lst;
    }

/// Generic join path function
/*
    Returns a string of joined vector tokens
*/
template < typename T, typename T_STR, typename T_LST >
    T_STR joinpath( const T_LST &p, const T sep )
    {   T_STR s;
        for ( typename T_LST::const_iterator it = p.begin(); it != p.end(); it++ )
        {   if ( s.length() ) s += sep; s += *it; }
        return s;
    }


// String types
typedef char t_levchar;
typedef std::basic_string< t_levchar > t_levstr;
typedef std::vector< t_levstr > t_levpath;
typedef std::vector< t_levpath > t_levpathlist;

// Sort compare for split paths
template< typename T, typename T_STR, typename T_LST > struct levcmp 
{   levcmp( const T_LST &p ) { m_p = p; }
    bool operator() ( const T_LST &i, const T_LST &j ) 
    { return levpath< T, T_STR, T_LST >( i, m_p ) < levpath< T, T_STR, T_LST >( j, m_p ); }
    T_LST m_p;
};

// Sort compare for strings
template< typename T, typename T_STR > struct levcmp_str 
{   levcmp_str( const T_STR &s ) { m_s = s; }
    bool operator() ( const T_STR &i, const T_STR &j ) 
    { return levstr< T, T_STR >( i, m_s ) < levstr< T, T_STR >( j, m_s ); }
    T_STR m_s;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    // Path to compare with
    const t_levchar* compare_path = "this/is/a/strange/path";

    // Paths to sort
    const t_levchar* path_list[] = 
    { 
        "this/is/a/strong/path",
        "that/is/a/strange/path",
        "this/is/a/strange",
        "this/is",
        "this/is/a",
        "this",
        "this/is/a/strange/path", 
        "is/this/a/strange/path", 
        "that/was",
        "completely/different/folder",
        0
    };

    printf( "\n----- String based Levenshtein ----\n"
            "Matching : %s\n\n", compare_path );

    // Create vector from paths         
    std::vector< t_levstr > paths;
    for( int i = 0; path_list[ i ]; i++ ) 
        paths.push_back( path_list[ i ] );

    // Sort the paths
    std::sort( paths.begin(), paths.end(), levcmp_str< t_levchar, t_levstr >( compare_path ) );

    // Show the result
    for ( std::vector< t_levstr >::iterator it = paths.begin(); it != paths.end(); it++ )
        printf( "%d : %s\n", 
                (int)levstr< t_levchar, t_levstr >( *it, compare_path ),
                (const char*)it->c_str() );

    printf( "\n----- Path based Levenshtein ----\n"
            "Matching : %s\n\n", compare_path );

    // Create vector from split paths
    t_levpath splitcompare = splitpath< t_levchar, t_levstr, t_levpath >( compare_path, '/' );
    t_levpathlist splitpaths;
    for ( int i = 0; path_list[ i ]; i++ ) 
        splitpaths.push_back( splitpath< t_levchar, t_levstr, t_levpath >( path_list[ i ], '/' ) );

    // Sort the paths
    std::sort( splitpaths.begin(), splitpaths.end(),
                levcmp< t_levchar, t_levstr, t_levpath >( splitcompare ) );

    // Show the results
    for ( t_levpathlist::iterator it = splitpaths.begin(); it != splitpaths.end(); it++ )
        printf( "%d : %s\n", 
                (int)levpath< t_levchar, t_levstr, t_levpath >( *it, splitcompare ),
                (const char*)joinpath< t_levchar, t_levstr, t_levpath >( *it, '/' ).c_str() );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Levenshtein seems like overkill.  Or maybe the question has changed.

Comment: You may be right, the question seemed to me to suggest there may not be exact matches in the path.

Comment: I hadn't considered that.  It's a definite possibility.  Or maybe he needs to handle links in the path too.  My answer doesn't handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have a ready C++ answer, but I had to do something similar in C# recently, and came up with the following:

Loop through the whole vector, checking the interesting path to see if it begins with an element.  The **longest** such match is the winner.  This would be an O(n) operation, depending upon the number of paths in the comparison set.

My refined version of the above became a little different, because I was going to be checking against a number of entries I'd already checked before.

So, I sorted the vector by descending length of path, so that the first match I come across would also be the best (giving me an average O(n/2) operation, I think), and stored results into a dictionary, so I wouldn't need to brute force the search again.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
//I don't know what path is, I'll pretend it's a std::string
//algorithm is the same, just functions change
const std::vector<boost::path>& services;
const std::string& findme = ???

std::vector<boost::path>::iterator result = services.end();
for(auto i = services.begin(); i != services.end(); ++i) {
     //if this path is shorter than the best so far, skip it
     if (result == services.end() || i->second.size()>result->second.size()) {
         const size_t colonpos = i->second.find(':', 8); //find colon
         //if this path is longer than findme, skip it
         if (findme.size() >= i->second.size()-colonpos) {
             //make sure they match, in _reverse_ order (faster in this case)
             int o=i->second.size()-1;
             for( ; o>=colonpos; --o) {
                 if (i->second[o] != findme[o-colonpos])
                     break;
             }
             //if it was a match, this is the new best result
             if (o < colonpos)
                 result = i;
         }
     }
}

//either result is services.end() meaning none matched
//or result is the _longest_ path that matched
```

Obviously, `boost::path` isn't a `std::string`, but probably has a member to get a `std::string` or similar object, so you'll just have to add that member to `i->second` and `result->second`